# Pass order data to AdForm tracking code in Woocommerce thankyou

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, tracking

I am looking to pass along the WooCommerce Variables "OrderID" and "Cart_total" into our Ad Tracking platform.

I was supplied with the tracking code which needed to be implemented and am having issues getting these variables into AdForm.

Here's the snippet, which works perfectly, I think that I am not including the variables correctly.

```
/**
 * @snippet       Add Conversion Tracking Code to Thank You Page
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19964
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 3.3.4
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page' );

function bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page() {
?>
<!-- Adform Tracking Code BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._adftrack = Array.isArray(window._adftrack) ? window._adftrack : (window._adftrack ? [window._adftrack] : []);
    window._adftrack.push({
        pm: XXXXXXXX,
        divider: encodeURIComponent('|'),
        pagename: encodeURIComponent('conversion'),
        order : { 
             sales: '$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();',
             orderid: '$order->get_id();'
        }
    });
    (function () { var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 'https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/'; var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); })();

</script>
<noscript>
    <p style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">
        <img src="https://track.adform.net/Serving/TrackPoint/?pm=XXXXXXX&ADFPageName=conversion&ADFdivider=|" width="1" height="1" alt="" />
    </p>
</noscript>
<!-- Adform Tracking Code END -->
<?php
}
```

Specifically, I was asked to provide the following variables:

```js
 sales: '$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();',
 orderid: '$order->get_id();'
```

But these are not working. I am unfortunately not a programmer (the programmer is on holiday). I think I need to call the variables somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more cart data in Order received (thankyou) page, so you surely mean `$order->get_total()`. Also there is some mistakes in your code.

So you need:

1. first to get the `WC_Order` object from the missing `$order_id` argument in your hoked function
2. To get order total
3. To include and **display** the values in the javascript code.

Try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page', 12, 1 );
function bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    ?>
    <!-- Adform Tracking Code BEGIN -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window._adftrack = Array.isArray(window._adftrack) ? window._adftrack : (window._adftrack ? [window._adftrack] : []);
        window._adftrack.push({
            pm: XXXXXXXX,
            divider: encodeURIComponent('|'),
            pagename: encodeURIComponent('conversion'),
            order : { 
                 sales: '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>',
                 orderid: '<?php echo $order->get_id(); ?>;'
            }
        });
        (function () { var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 'https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/'; var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); })();

    </script>
    <noscript>
        <p style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">
            <img src="https://track.adform.net/Serving/TrackPoint/?pm=XXXXXXX&ADFPageName=conversion&ADFdivider=|" width="1" height="1" alt="" />
        </p>
    </noscript>
    <!-- Adform Tracking Code END -->
    <?php
}
```